# In the site page list, when clicking on a page, how to make it open in a new tab (or the same tab)?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a setting in SPO to control, on the site page list, when clicking on a page, whether the page opens in the current tab or in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior in SharePoint Online. By default, SharePoint links open in the same tab in the modern pages. SharePoint will open external links in quick links WebPart or navigation automatically in a new tab.

For internal links, there’s no out-of-the-box setting to generally open links in a new tab.

More info:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/open-new-tab-instead-of-same-window-in-sharepoint-online/m-p/3257351

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/links-in-site-contents-no-longer-opening-in-new/d4a6c3f2-e612-4037-92b2-7a9c85e06163